# Why do both of the random numbers I create be the same everytime in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, random, integer

Why are RandomInt1 and RandomInt2 always the same number each time I run my code?

```
    Dim RandomGen1 As New Random
    Dim RandomInt1 As Integer
    RandomInt1 = RandomGen1.Next(2, 7)

    Dim RandomGen2 As New Random
    Dim RandomInt2 As Integer
    RandomInt2 = RandomGen2.Next(2, 7)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but whenever you find yourself doing the same thing with a lot of related variables then you should think about using arrays or some other data structure.

Answer (score 4):

Mind-blowing fun fact: there is no such thing as a [truly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers) random number in computers, the .NET framework's implementation of this concept has a relationship to your problem.

When you start your program using .NET, each random number generator you make (within a given scope) will yield the same sequence of numbers. The sequence of results you will get were already determined, when your program started, by a seed that was somehow selected by the instance. Any randomization that starts with this seed yields the same sequence of numbers. It's fate.

The solution is to use only one "generator" (or "fate processor") and just keep calling the `.Next` method when you need a new number. Your project sounds cool, but I edited your post to be as clear as possible. Good luck:

```
    Dim RandomGen1 As New Random
    Dim RandomInt1 As Integer
    RandomInt1 = RandomGen1.Next(2, 7)

    'notice I did not make a RandomGen2, it will just give me the same numbers as RandomGen1
    Dim RandomInt2 As Integer
    RandomInt2 = RandomGen1.Next(2, 7)
```

Comment: Technically the numbers are not predetermined, there is no large file or database of numbers that get returned.  They are just produced mathematically in a way that always returns the same sequence from a given seed.

Comment: ok, they are determined by the formula and the seed? pre-determined? c'mon : ) srsly

Comment: Sort of, the sequence of numbers isn't always known at program startup.  The seed can be provided programatically from a source such as a timer or from user input.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue or say you are wrong, I think you gave a good answer.  I just want to make sure that the person asking the question fully understands what is happening.

Comment: I thought about what you said a bit, and I think I agree with what you are saying now. You're right, its not stored in memory, its not already calculated.  It must be requested. Its determined but not predetermined. Its more like fated.

Comment: from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) `The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers`

Comment: @BradleyUffner The sequence of number might not be always known, but it will be always the same for a given seed, so it allows you to repeat the 'same' sequence of random numbers (some people need that). In some games, it conserves the seed so if the user reloads a game because he lost, the game will behave the same if the user does, even with random numbers.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help, I honestly did not expect an answer so quick. I will get right away to fixing it. :)